# Get features onclick ArcGIS JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-portal

I am new to JavaScript and to JavaScript APIs as well,

I am trying to get all the attributes of a feature that is clicked on the webmap, and I don't want to use the default pop up so I disabled it, and wrote the function below. I get the geometry, but I want the actual feature.

How can I do this?

Here is the current code I have which always returns 0 features when I do the query based on the geometry or mappoint.

```
 view.on("click", async function(event){
        view.hitTest(event).then(
            async function(response){
            for(let j=0;j<=response.results.length-1;j++){
                var graphic = response.results[j].graphic;
                
                let featureLayer=graphic.layer;
                let lyrType  =featureLayer.operationalLayerType;
                if(lyrType!='ArcGISFeatureLayer')
                    continue;
                var query = featureLayer.createQuery();
                query.geometry = graphic.geometry; // I also tried event.mapPoint
                query.outFields= ["*"];
                query.spatialRelationship = "intersects";
                let rr= await featureLayer.queryFeatures(query);
                let numberOfSelectedFeatures=rr.features.length;  // this is 0, unless i remove the query then it gets every feature in the layer          
                }
         
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you use functions async way, but there is an example in the documentation.

[HitTest sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/view-hittest/)

```
view.on("pointer-down", eventHandler);
function eventHandler(event) {
  view.hitTest(event).then(function (response) {
    if (response.results.length) {
      const graphic = response.results[0].graphic;
      const attributes = graphic.attributes;
      console.log(attributes);
    }
  });
}
```

If FeatureLayer' features have attributes and you want to get all attributes, you should define `outFields` property as `["*"]`.

```
const layer = new FeatureLayer({
  // URL to the service
  url: "url,
  outFields: ["*"]
});
```

OR

```
featureLayer.outFields = ["*"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, however as you can see from my code, I already do this, but I want to access the feature not the graphic, the attributes that are retrieved from graphic are not all the attributes of the feature. So I want to access the Feature, not the Graphic so I can load it, and get all it's attributes.

Comment: Can you try defining outFields on layer? If you want to get all attributes you should define outfields like; featureLayer.outFields = ["*"]

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#outFields . If this works, I will edit my answer. It's work on my sample. @ZZZ

Comment: The outfields are set to be * in the Webmap, they all appear when using the regular default esri popup. I don't know why the response graphic (Selected Feature on the map) only gives 2 attributes, ObjectId and Shape. I decided to query the feature using the object id and it worked, but I think there is something weird going on because in my mind I shouldn't have to do all of this to get the feature